# How do I get my iPhone to type a . instead of the word period?

Tags: iphone, siri, voice-dictation

Ever since the last software update to iOS 14.2, Siri is very inconsistent about when to type punctuation for a period.  It seems to only affect certain contacts, and is inconsistent in emails.  For some contacts, all I can get it to type is the word period.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don’t understand how this may be connected to certain contacts? If you‘re referring to text dictation, „full stop“ works here.